# Is there anyway to customize the input() function of Sikuli?

Tags: input, sikuli

As we know when we use `input()` in Sikuli, popup box appears. By typing in it, the user can give input to the program.  But if we want to give two (or more than two) inputs/arguments to the program, we have to call `input()` again and again.

Rather than doing this, is there any way that I could customize `input()` and make multiple fields appear all in a single GUI prompt, other than using a Jython module?

Answer (score 2):

No, there is not.

Sikuli is a library for using computer vision on the screen, and for performing GUI operations automatically.  If you need to do anything beyond the most rudimentary interaction with a live human, you need to use libraries that are intended for that.